# While opening PDP page throws exception in magento 2

Tags: product, custom-options, magento-2.2.5, product-view

I have imported product options in magento 2
But It throws following error, Please provide me a solution

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument
>   supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/html/cpap/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php
>   on line 215

Answer (score 0):

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php

```
/**
 * Get json representation of
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getJsonConfig()
{
    $config = [];
    foreach ($this->getOptions() as $option) {
        /* @var $option \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option */
        if ($option->hasValues()) {
            $tmpPriceValues = [];
            foreach ($option->getValues() as $valueId => $value) {
                $tmpPriceValues[$valueId] = $this->_getPriceConfiguration($value);
            }
            $priceValue = $tmpPriceValues;
        } else {
            $priceValue = $this->_getPriceConfiguration($option);
        }
        $config[$option->getId()] = $priceValue;
    }

    $configObj = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'config' => $config,
        ]
    );

    //pass the return array encapsulated in an object for the other modules to be able to alter it eg: weee
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_option_price_configuration_after', ['configObj' => $configObj]);

    $config=$configObj->getConfig();

    return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
}
```

In your case **$option->getValues()** returns null, this should retuns array. So quick fix is:

```
/**
 * Get json representation of
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getJsonConfig()
{
    $config = [];
    foreach ($this->getOptions() as $option) {
        /* @var $option \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option */
        if ($option->hasValues()) {
            $tmpPriceValues = [];
            if (is_array($option->getValues())) {
                foreach ($option->getValues() as $valueId => $value) {
                    $tmpPriceValues[$valueId] = $this->_getPriceConfiguration($value);
                }
            }
            $priceValue = $tmpPriceValues;
        } else {
            $priceValue = $this->_getPriceConfiguration($option);
        }
        $config[$option->getId()] = $priceValue;
    }

    $configObj = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'config' => $config,
        ]
    );

    //pass the return array encapsulated in an object for the other modules to be able to alter it eg: weee
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_option_price_configuration_after', ['configObj' => $configObj]);

    $config=$configObj->getConfig();

    return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
}
```

**Note:** *Overwrite this class. Don't modify the core file*

Comment: but is this a correct way or how would i find which option is null

Comment: You can set debug log getJsonConfig() and check.

Comment: Actually i have done what you have said, but it throws exception from other file

Comment: Can you suggest me, how to remove custom options, if it value is null